# HTML onclick function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am wondering why my onclick function doesn't work in this particular case. My function is a pretty straightforward alert:

```
function confirmEditProduct(editProductID){
      alert("Worked");
  }
```

This is my HTML code echoed in PHP:

```
    echo "
      <img src='$directory/$productImage' width='200px;'></img><br><br>
      <p>Product Name: <p><input type='text' id='editName' name='editName' style='width:400px;' value='$productName'/>
      <p>Category:
          <select class='form-control' id='editCat' style='width:200px;' disabled>
            <option value='Cacti'"; if ($productCategory == '1') echo " selected='selected'"; echo ">Cacti</option>
            <option value='Succulents'"; if ($productCategory == '2') echo " selected='selected'"; echo ">Succulents</option>
          </select>

      <p>Description: <p><textarea rows='4' cols='50' id='editDesc' name='editDesc'>$productDesc</textarea>
      <p>Price: <input type='text' id='editPrice' name='editPrice' value='$productPrice'/>
      <p>Image: <input class='input-group' type='file' id='editImage' name='editImage' accept='image/*' />
      <p>Stock: <input type='text' id='editStock' name='editStock' value='$productStock'/>
      <p>
      <input type='button' class='btn btn-success' id='$productID' onClick='confirmEditProduct($productID);' value='Edit Product' />


  ";
```

This snippet is part of a modal btw.

Thank you to everyone who can help me out

Comment: Is your js function global?

Comment: how do i find that out? it's on my main.js file.

Comment: Can you show that code?

Comment: do you have any errors in the developer tools console? if `$productID` is not a numeric value, then you need to put quotes around it

Comment: i think i should mention that this code results to a generation of a couple of modals which contains the edit product button.

Comment: $productID is a numeric value.

Comment: i can't put double quotes because it's an echo

Comment: even if i remove the parameters the function still won't work

Comment: nevermind, you answered the second part of my question, being numeric it's OK without the **escaped** quotes I briefly had as a comment (which would work, but is not important now) - what about the first part? **Any errors in the developer tools console** when you click the button?

Comment: I'm using Atom, not sure if there's a developer tools console here, but I'll try to find out

Comment: Nevermind, I now realize taht you mean the console in the browser haha wait

Comment: The error is VM4004 admin.php:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: confirmEditProduct is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Comment: Okay I got an initial solution. I moved my code for this particular function from main.js to the page where the html will appear (admin.php) and it now works. Why won't it get the function from main.js?

Answer (score 2):

This seems like it would be quite simple. Are you also echoing the Javascript? If so, take an extra precaution and move it before the HTML code. Some other things you may want to consider include making the input button into a straight up button and omitting the semicolon at the end of the onclick attribute. As for styling, you may want to put the value attribute after the type attribute. Hope this helps!

Edit:
When I mean echoing the Javascript, make sure you have a `<script src="main.js">` or the entire script within your echoed code.

Comment: What does it mean to "take an extra precaution and move it before the HTML code"? Yes I am also echoing the javascript. If there's a better way to do it please let me know :)

Comment: My personal preference is to use a `<button type="button">`, if it's not nested within a form, and you want to use inline JS. I am not sure if this makes a difference...

Comment: I have new info: on the console there is an error that says: VM4004 admin.php:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: confirmEditProduct is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Comment: As others said too, your function should be global, not nested within another function. 

Try this code:

     `<button type='button' class='btn btn-success' id='$productID' onclick='confirmEditProduct($productID);' >Edit Product</button>`

Comment: You may want to put the function within the echoed text in the echoed text,
`echo "
<script>
function confirmEditProduct(editProductID){
      alert("Worked");
  }
</script>
...
      <input type='button' class='btn btn-success' id='$productID' onClick='confirmEditProduct($productID);' value='Edit Product' />

";`

Comment: Okay I got an initial solution. I moved my code for this particular function from main.js to the page where the html will appear (admin.php) and it now works. Why won't it get the function from main.js?

Comment: Make sure you are including it using `<script src="main.js"></script>`, and using correct directory traversing if the files are not on the same level. I sometimes forget to do both of these. Also, if you're working with a team, make sure the script file is still "main.js" and not something else.